# repl.it javascript rock, paper, scissors assignment. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, debugging

As one of my class assignments, I'm tasked with fixing the broken code on repl.it site. [repl.it rock, paper scissors](https://repl.it/@angelrodriguez2/rockpaperscissors). Although this topic has been brought up many times, I cannot find any threads with code similar to this one. They are all very different.

I know that the main issues are:

1. The prompt states the computer always wins even if the user wins. I added user input logic in order to return a result for the user winning.
2. Game ignores "Rock" as user input. I added a toLowerCase() method to remove uppercase characters.
3. The computer always ignores selecting "rock". I changed Math.ceil to Math.floor so that the function randomFrom also includes the 0 index of the computerChoices array.
4. Correctly read and store user input (I can't figure out how to make this work other than creating an input variable. I console logged this but no luck so far.

Here is the original code:

```js
let computerChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

function randomFrom(array) {
return array[(Math.ceil(Math.random()*3)) ];
console.log(array);
}


function checkInput(input, computerChoices) {
  if (input == "quit") {
    return true;
  }
  
  let computerChoice = randomFrom(computerChoices);
  
if(computerChoice === "rock" && input === "scissors"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === "scissors" && input === "paper"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === "paper" && input === "rock"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
}

alert("Computer wins!");``
return false
}

function start(gameOver, computerChoices) {
  while (!gameOver){
    let playerInput = '';
    prompt("Hi! Enter rock/paper/scissors to play, or quit to stop playing.");
gameOver = checkInput(playerInput, computerChoices);
playerInput = "paper";

} 
}

let gameOver = false;

start(gameOver, computerChoices)
```

I've also included my code with comments. I'm not quite understanding everything that's going on here. I know it's also a scope issue but I'm just not seeing it. I'm not asking anyone to solve this for me, but at least let me know if I'm headed in the right direction or if I made the code worse than when I started. If you do solve it, please add more comments. Thank you!

```js
//Is gameOver defined correctly? I'm not sure. 
let gameOver = false;
let computerChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let computerChoice = randomFrom(computerChoices);
console.log(computerChoice);

// //change Math.ceil to Math.floor in order to include the [0] index
function randomFrom(array) {
return array[(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
}

//Changed computerChoices to computerChoice
function checkInput(input, computerChoice) {
  if (input === "quit") {
    return true;
  }

//Changed computerChoices to computerChoice
function startGame(gameOver, computerChoice) {
  while (!gameOver){
    let playerInput = '';
    //Added input in order to change user input to lowercase characters
    let input = playerInput.toLowerCase();
    prompt("Hi! Enter rock/paper/scissors to play, or quit to stop playing.");
} 
  
if(computerChoice === "rock" && input === "scissors"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === "scissors" && input === "paper"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === "paper" && input === "rock"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
//Added user outcomes since program results in the computer always winning
} else if(computerChoice === "rock" && input === "paper"){
alert("Player wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === "scissors" && input === "rock"){
alert("Player wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === "paper" && input === "scissors"){
alert("Computer wins!");
return true;
} else if (computerChoice === input) {
alert("we have a draw");
} else {
console.log("error");
}

}
//I'm calling the startGame() function in order to get it to run
return startGame();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things here:

- Some functions where defined inside another function, so you can't call them
- I removed all those unnecassary parameters and return statements
- I defined `input` outside the `startGame()` function to make it accasable inside `checkInput()` -- Passing `input` as a parameter would be fine, too
- I also removed that invalid and unnecassary while loop inside `startGame()`
- `startGame()` was inside `checkInput()` so it never got called, therefore the game never started

```js
//Is gameOver defined correctly? I'm not sure. 
let gameOver = false;
let input;
let computerChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let computerChoice = randomFrom(computerChoices);
console.log(computerChoice);

// //change Math.ceil to Math.floor in order to include the [0] index
function randomFrom(array) {
  return array[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))];
}

//Changed computerChoices to computerChoice
function startGame() {
  //Added input in order to change user input to lowercase characters
  input = prompt("Hi! Enter rock/paper/scissors to play, or quit to stop playing.").toLowerCase();
  checkInput();
}

//Changed computerChoices to computerChoice
function checkInput() {
  if (input === "quit") {
    return;
  }


  if (computerChoice === "rock" && input === "scissors") {
    alert("Computer wins!");
  } else if (computerChoice === "scissors" && input === "paper") {
    alert("Computer wins!");
  } else if (computerChoice === "paper" && input === "rock") {
    alert("Computer wins!");
    //Added user outcomes since program results in the computer always winning
  } else if (computerChoice === "rock" && input === "paper") {
    alert("Player wins!");
  } else if (computerChoice === "scissors" && input === "rock") {
    alert("Player wins!");
  } else if (computerChoice === "paper" && input === "scissors") {
    alert("Computer wins!");
  } else if (computerChoice === input) {
    alert("we have a draw");
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }

}
//I'm calling the startGame() function in order to get it to run
startGame();
```

Keep in mind that you'll need a loop if you want the game to last longer than just one round.

Secondly, here's a working example as SO decided to show some error that I didn't encounter when testing anywhere else than stacksnippets: http://jsfiddle.net/zvao25ny/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I replaced the "else" closing statement with "return startGame();" to loop through and restart the game after each single round.

Comment: @Angel Glad to help! Also nice to see you've managed to loop the game -- but you don't need this `return` statement. It's not "wrong" or anything, but just unnassecary.